# Singleton search context for search api

Tags: content-search, lucene, dependency-injection

Typical usage of search api uses a using statement to dispose of the search context.

```cs
 using (var context = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex(_indexName).CreateSearchContext())
 {
     var hits = context.GetQueryable<SearchResult>();
     return hits;
 }
```

This runs into a problem with hits.result or lucene reader being disposed  before it can be used by the calling method. This may be more likely if creating a search service rather than calling this (for example) within an MVC controller.

Often this disposal problem is addressed by calling ToList() creating an `IEnumerable<SearchResult>` and returning that instead.

```
return hits.ToList()
```

By doing this, we loose hits.GetResults() and the properties within - `Hits`, `TotalSearchResults` and `Facets`

An alternative approach mentioned is to use a single search context that is not disposed and instead reused across the application.

### Question

- Is using a single, reused context a good approach?
- Are there any
  pitfalls?
- Are there any good code examples of doing this, possibly
  with a dependency injection framework handling a singleton.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Is using a single, reused context a good approach?

Yes. It is the recommended approach.

### Are there any pitfalls?

Yes. New documents added to your indexes will not show, until you re-open a new Search Context. So you may need to tie in your SearchContext to index update events.

### Are there any good code examples of doing this, possibly with a dependency injection framework handling a singleton.

Because of the pitfalls, setting this up in a DI Singleton is probably not a good idea. For an on-source reference and explanation, see [Sitecore 7 Patterns for Global Search Context Reuse](https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/sitecore_7_development_team/posts/sitecore-7-patterns-for-global-search-context-reuse)